# Failed to load resource : 404 error when changing ASP.NET MVC server from IIS Express to Local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, iis-10

I wanted to host my ASP.NET MVC app in a LAN network. So I changed the server to Local IIS and that's when the 404 error appeared. Only the home page is loading ok, but all actions in controller that I have defined in my app are not found and the 404 error is being thrown.

Maybe I got it wrong when configuring IIS or my app. Please help!

I have already tried the  but i didn't help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: to enable logging select site in iis and then double click on the logging feature of the iis and select enable from the action pane. and for Site not reachable check your iis site bindings and typed url. or you can select the site and click browse from the action pane.

Answer (score 0):

check .net version for this apppool at iss and version of your target framework in your project.

Comment: My App Poll is having v4.0 and my project target .net is 4.6.1.

Comment: so thats should be fine. dod you just copied bin folder ? or did you made proper 'publish' to folder ? it is not .net core? usual .net framework?

Comment: The only thing I did is changed that IIS Express to Local IIS in the Project Properties --> Web.

Comment: publish it and try load into website in iis on server not from visual studio
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwbKquNBNgQ

Comment: I did what was specified in a video you provided, but now I'm getting the issue with "Site not reachable"...

Comment: check logs in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\ yourWebsiteIISID

Comment: Looks like there're no logs for my site at all there. I ran my url again but it didn't append any log file in a specified path.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue while playing a video uploaded through the same application.
It was playing on my local machine while but when I published the project I was giving 
Failed to load resource 404 error.

**It was MIME Types error the video/mp4 was not added in IIS MIME Types.**

[follow these steps to add MIME Type in IIS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/to-overcome-http-error-404-3-not-found/)